# checkout from svn using ant

Tags: svn, ant

I am trying to checkout from svn using ant from Linux machine. I have written build.xml but it is showing me the error.

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="SVN" default="build" basedir=".">
<property name="ANT_HOME" value="/dun/d67loc1/software/apache-ant-1.6.5"/>
<path id="svnant.classpath">
<pathelement location="${ANT_HOME}/lib"/>
<fileset dir="${ANT_HOME}/lib/">
<include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath"/>
<target name="checkout">
<echo>svn checkout </echo>
<svn username="...." password="....">
<checkout url="https://svm.acnielsen.com/repos/IDOArchitecture/Ascent/Bin/Config/trunk/Production/TIBCO/FavConfig" destPath="SRC" />
</svn>
</target>
<target name="build" depends="checkout">
<description>Main target</description>
</target>
</project>
```

While executing it I am getting the below error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

checkout:
     [echo] svn checkout
      [svn] <Checkout> started ...
      [svn] svn: handshake_failure: remotely generated; fatal
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/IDOArchitecture/Ascent/Bin/Config/trunk/Production/TIBCO/FavConfig'
      [svn] svn: handshake_failure: remotely generated; fatal
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/IDOArchitecture/Ascent/Bin/Config/trunk/Production/TIBCO/FavConfig'
      [svn] <Checkout> failed !

BUILD FAILED
/home/tibco/ReleaseManagement/svn_test/build.xml:13: Can't checkout

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<target name="checkout">    
   <exec executable="svn" dir="${where to checkout}">
       <arg line=" co url --username=###### --password=######"/>
   </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: but how to use the url (the location from where i want to checkout)

Comment: @maitree : sorry I forget that. Check the answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the .bash Profile for Java Home it should point to actual JDK home and JRE version. If it points to right directory it will be ok.

Comment: I don't see how the Java home directory relates to the error message reported in the question.